# neo4j count nodes with case statment

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this query :

```
match (campaign:Campaign)<-[:CREATED_FOR]-(facebookAlbum:FacebookAlbum)
where campaign.id="54b509ec851dd"  
return case when campaign.isOpeningAlbum=0 then facebookAlbum 
when campaign.isOpeningAlbum=1 then 1 end as result
ORDER BY facebookAlbum.openTime DESC LIMIT 1
```

I'm trying to return also the amount of facebookAlbums connected to the campaign, i try something like this:

```
match (campaign:Campaign)<-[:CREATED_FOR]-(facebookAlbum:FacebookAlbum) 
where campaign.id="54b509ec851dd" 
 return case when campaign.isOpeningAlbum=0 then facebookAlbum 
when campaign.isOpeningAlbum=1 then 1 end as   result,count(facebookAlbum) as count 
ORDER BY facebookAlbum.openTime DESC LIMIT 1
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Unknown identifier `facebookAlbum`
```

I'm adding a link to an example db- http://console.neo4j.org/r/afozkf

From this graphDB, i need to get the facebookAlbum with the highest openTime and the amount of facebookAlbums connected to the campaign.
I'm checking also the isOpeningAlbum prop of the campaign. If it's 0 ok, if it's 1 then return is_opening_album=1

Comment: you might find it easier to get answers if you create and share a console here [ http://console.neo4j.org/ ]    with your initial data and problem query.

Comment: @cechode Thanks! I've just edited the question with the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seems like you're using an aggregation `count(facebookAlbum)` (2nd when) and the unaggregated `facebookAlbum` (1st when and in order by) in the same statement - which seem to confuse Cypher (and myself as well).

### addendum based on refined question

Try the following:

```
MATCH (campaign:Campaign { id:'123' })
OPTIONAL MATCH (campaign)-[:CREATED_FOR]->(facebookAlbum)
WITH campaign, facebookAlbum
ORDER BY facebookAlbum.openTime DESC 
RETURN campaign.id, campaign.isOpeningAlbum = 1 AS opening, 
       head(collect(facebookAlbum)) AS firstAlbum, 
       count(facebookAlbum) AS count
```

This statement assumes that there are campaigns not having any albums - therefore using the `OPTIONAL MATCH`. The `WITH` and `ORDER BY` are used to make sure the albums are in timely order. The final return uses `head(collect())` to find the first album and `count` is self describing.

In case you have a lot of albums connected to a campaign you might consider refactoring your graph model. The albums basically form a linked list based on creation time. Using `NEXT` or `PREV` relationships you can make that structure explicit in the graph and speed up your query a lot.

Comment: I'm trying to return the newest facebookAlbum and the amount of facebookAlbums that connected to the campaign.

So the order by is to get the newest album and the count is for the amount

Comment: Great, thanks! If the creation of the facebookAlbums are happening not at the same time. I mean, once a facebook album is full, a new one is opened. so it's one by one.
You still recommend to  refactoring my graph model?